# Как обновить стиль span'а при смене данных на ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, span

Есть 5 значений, хранящихся в db

1. ratecount1
2. ratecount2
3. ratecount3
4. ratecount4
5. ratecount5

На основе этих значений выводится процентное соотношение каждого из значений.
Пример кода php с формулой

```
str_replace(",", ".", round((100/($row['ratecount1']+$row['ratecount2']+$row['ratecount3']+$row['ratecount4']+$row['ratecount5']))*$row['ratecount1'], 2))
```

результат подсчета записывается в переменную `{vote-percent-5}`, которая добавляет в `span % width`

```
<span class="bar-5" style="width:{vote-percent-5}%"></span>
```

Теперь главное, при голосовании за **"5"** идет обновление при помощи `ajax` переменной `ratecount5`, выглядит на `js` так

```
if ( data.success ) {
        var rating = data.rating;

        rating = rating.replace(/&lt;/g, "<");
        rating = rating.replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
        rating = rating.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");

        $("#ratig-layer-" + id).html(rating);
        $(".reviews-num").html(data.votenum);
        $(".bar-number-1").html(data.ratecount1);
        $(".bar-number-2").html(data.ratecount2);
        $(".bar-number-3").html(data.ratecount3);
        $(".bar-number-4").html(data.ratecount4);
        $(".bar-number-5").html(data.ratecount5);
    }
```

Вопрос в том, как мне при помощи ajax в функции выше обновить процентное соотношение в блоке

```
<span class="bar-5" style="width:{vote-percent-5}%"></span>
```

на основе новых обновившихся данных.
Вот что это все представляет в куче
[image: скрин]

эту самую полоску мне и необходимо обновлять

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что это не оптимальное решение, но должно работать. Насколько я понял, у Вас в data.ratecount1 приходит кол-во уже поставленных звезд, и на основе их происходит расчет. Лучше было бы получить эти значения из PHP, а в JS просто изменить ширину...

```js
var data = {
 ratecount1: 1,
 ratecount2: 1,
 ratecount3: 2,
 ratecount4: 1,
 ratecount5: 2,
}

var width,
 arrOfRatecount = [data.ratecount1, data.ratecount2, data.ratecount3, data.ratecount4, data.ratecount5],
 sumOfRatecounts = data.ratecount1 + data.ratecount2 + data.ratecount3 + data.ratecount4 + data.ratecount5;

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
 width = Math.round(100 / sumOfRatecounts * arrOfRatecount[i]);
 $('.bar-' + ( i + 1 ) ).css({
  'width': width + '%'
 });
}
```

```css
.bar-1,
.bar-2,
.bar-3,
.bar-4,
.bar-5 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
.wrapper{
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper" >
  <div>
    <span class="bar-1" style="width:0px"></span>  
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="bar-2" style="width:0px"></span>  
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="bar-3" style="width:0px"></span>  
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="bar-4" style="width:0px"></span>  
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="bar-5" style="width:0px"></span>  
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, работает но с ошибкой в проставлении % соотношения.Если я голосую за 5, то все нормально, обновляет ширину на 100%
100/(5+0+0+0+0)*5=100
http://prntscr.com/gmvwom
Если я ставлю оценку 4, то ставиться ширина 10%
Если 3 то 1%
http://prntscr.com/gmvwg2
Если 2 то 0%
Если 1 то 0%
http://prntscr.com/gmvwx7
Как бы поправить

Comment: @DooMDiM  Все работает. Можете попробовать тут [plnkr](https://jsfiddle.net/nnu9hz4v/) . Меняйте данные в data и ширина меняется. Может есть какие-то особенности применения именно у Вас на странице.

Comment: @DooMDiM Плюс попробуйте вывести все переменные data.ratecount в console.log(). Может туда приходит что-то не то